# Typescript I can't index in the object ,which has many maybe object type

Tags: javascript, typescript

```
interface type1 {
    ttis: string,
    time: string
}

interface type2 {
    time: string,
    c2: number
}

type nameType1 = 'ttis' | 'time';

type nameType2 = 'c2' | 'time';

function testFun (v: type1[] | type2[], yKey: nameType1 | nameType2) {
    for (const item of v) {
        console.log(item[yKey]) // Property 'ttis' does not exist on type 'type1 | type2'.
    }
}
```

The v array has many types of element that is an object, and I want to index these objects using a yKey, but the error always up show

Comment: What you are doing is not safe; someone could call `testFun([{ ttis: "", time: "" }], "c2");`.  If you want to actual restrict `testFun()` so that the array and the keys need to be correlated, you can do it with generics like [this](https://tsplay.dev/W4O0Bm).  Does that meet your needs? If so I can write up an answer; if not, please clarify what I'm missing.

Comment: Someone already wrote that answer and then deleted it because it allowed a mixed type array of T1 and T2 when the original intention of the question seems to be an array of all T1s or all T2s

Comment: @jcalz It seems will pop up errors when I use this solution like your example code. I need to index the value in one of  objects of array using the yKey.

Comment: "It seems will pop up errors".  Please show me what you mean with a [mre], otherwise it's impossible for me to advise further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a [generic constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) for the value type, and then use [`keyof`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/keyof-types.html) to restrict the allowed keys:

```
interface Type1 {
    ttis: string,
    time: string
}

interface Type2 {
    time: string,
    c2: number
}

function testFun<T extends Type1 | Type2>(v: T[], yKey: keyof T) {
    for (const item of v) {
        console.log(item[yKey]);
    }
}
```

Comment: While this works and I'm hoping this satisfies OP usecase, their original question explicitly wants `v` to be a full array of only 1 type or another, not a mixed array of both types. So `testFun([{ttis: 'a', time: 'b'}, {c2: 1, time: 'b'}], 'ttis')` would be fine here even though it's not intended by the original question (and will yield undefined in the second console log)

Comment: @Azarro Fair point.

Comment: It really depends on the use cases; this version is the "standard" way of doing things in TypeScript, even though there is the hole you point out.  Without a feature like [ms/TS#27808](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27808) it's difficult to get something where the compiler only accepts valid code and only rejects invalid code.  If it really matters, you could add an overload signature like [this](//tsplay.dev/mMM6zm), but overloads are not checked strictly by the compiler so you can do unsafe things, see [ms/TS#10765](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10765).

Comment: Since you'll never get fully "correct" behavior from the compiler, one needs to determine which sorts of incorrect behaviors are more tolerable than others, and code accordingly.

Comment: If you want to go crazy you can use the fix for [ms/TS#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581) at [ms/TS#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109) involving "distributive object types", like [this](https://tsplay.dev/w65ZGW). But it's much more complicated and probably too esoteric for most developers, and there are *still* holes you can exploit with this technique (although I can't see any in this particular example) so it's all about diminishing returns.  (Oh, these past three comments are responding to @Azarro if it matters)

Comment: @jcalz When it comes to TypeScript, you're an inspiration, pure and simple.

Comment: Yup which is why I agree that if this hopefully is okay for OP's case, that's great! But it isn't exactly what OP wanted (which is very hard to do at present with compile time checks). At the end of the day, the tradeoffs you're okay with making are important :) (Side note: Deleted my answer- I was offbase with thinking a few steps tangential re: index signatures, was trying to find a discussion in an issue that dealt with a scenario like OP's but looks like I was on the wrong rabbithole of issues).